# How can I create a premium user to test premium features of my app in production when using Stripe in test mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, stripe-payments

I am working on an app that allows members to upgrade to premium membership (after paying with Stripe) for access to additional features.  I am using Stripe in test mode only in production, and so therefore am looking for a way to create a premium user in the Heroku console. Would it be something like this?:

```
user = User.find_by(name:’existing user name’)
user.update_attribute(‘premium’).save
```

I have `t.boolean  "premium"` in my schema.rb file.

I am new to programming, so please let me know if you need any additional file information.  Thanks!

Edit update:  Here is my charges controller code:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @stripe_btn_data = {
      key: "#{ Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] }",
      description: 'Premium Membership',
      amount: 1_299

    }
   end


   def create

   @amount = params[:amount]


   customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
     email: current_user.email,
     card: params[:stripeToken]
   )

   charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
     customer: customer.id, 
     amount: @amount,
     description: 'Premium Membership',
     currency: 'usd'
   )

   current_user.update_attribute(:premium, true)

   redirect_to wikis_path, flash: { notice: "Congratulations, #{current_user.email}, on becoming a premium member!"}


 rescue Stripe::CardError => e
   flash[:error] = e.message
   redirect_to new_charge_path
 end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that in your controller you call a method that creates a new Stripe charge, like so:

```
@user.update_with_payment
```

Inside that method in the user model you should be calling on the Stripe API to charge the user based on their stripe token. What you can do is set a condition on that method so that if the charge is successful, you update the user to make their premium attribute true. If the charge is unsuccessful, you re-render the payment form and display any applicable errors.

```
if @user.update_with_payment
  @user.update_attribute(:premium, true)
  # You can than redirect wherever you want
  redirect_to @user
else
  render :new
end
```

Setting your controller up this way will enable users on the Stripe test mode to be able to receive the premium attribute on their object, since the test mode will run this method just like live mode. When setting up methods and logic for Stripe, put all of your logic into your Rails app, and test mode will work the way you expect live mode to work. Don't update user objects in the console.

Comment: I understand the concept, but I do not have @user.update_with_payment in my charges controller or anywhere else in my code.  Do you have another suggestion now that I've posted my charges controller?  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to explicitly update that user in the database without changing code, then you can just do what `fourfourjew` suggested at the top -- grab a user (`user = User.find(1)`) and then use AR's `update_attribute` method, which takes the attribute, and then the value to set it to as arguments: `user.update_attribute(:premium, true)`

Comment: Sasha, is there a reason that fourfourjew mentioned to not update user objects in the console?  Will it potentially mess up my database in production?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. It looks like he was just suggesting one way to structure your controller to do what you want. His way isn't the only way, and you can update a user wherever you want. He's suggesting encapsulating more of the Stripe behavior in your User model, instead of in the controller. Although this is a slightly Railsier way to do it (fat models, skinny controllers), you are welcome to follow either path.